# Añadir write csv a mi función python

Tags: python

Necesitaría que al ejecutar mi función también me sacara un csv, he probado así pero no me llega a escribir nada, tan solo llego a crear el csv en el notebook, también me gustaría que se grabara en disco no el home de jupyter.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from csv import DictWriter


f = open('huevos.csv','w')

class mkcloud():
    def __init__(self, datos):

    self.datos=datos

def imprimir(self):
    #print("Canal:", self.canal, "\nVersion:", self.version)
    #print(df)


    #add columns and format
    self.datos['Canal'] = "email"
    self.datos['CampaignID'] = 'md19'
    self.datos['FechaCarga'] = '29/07/2019'
    self.datos['Version'] = '1'
    self.datos['locale'] = "es"

    print(self.datos)


    #export/write to disk................R:\_TDig
   # Initialise data to lists. 
   data = [{'a': 'cod_persona2'}, {'a':'cod_persona'}] 

   # Creates DataFrame. 
   df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

  mk= mkcloud(df)
  mk.imprimir()
 with f:

writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(mk)
```

Podría definir una función para exportar a csv? a ver si me podeis ayudar. La salida sería un dataframe no una lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que pandas tiene sus propios metodos para leer archivos csv y crear un dataFrame en base a ellos, [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) y para guardar un DataFrame en un csv [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Deberías usar este último en vez del módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar de Python:

```
mk.datos.to_csv("huevos.csv", index=False)
```

---

La causa por la que `writer.writerows(mk)` no funciona es porque `writerrows` espera un iterable con las filas a escribir en el csv y las instancias de tu clase `mkcloud` no son iterables.

Puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples` para iterar sobre las filas del DataFrame:

```
with open('huevos.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(mk.datos.itertuples())
```

o podrías hacer tu clase iterable:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


class MkCloud:

    def __init__(self, datos):
        self.datos = datos

    def imprimir(self):
        #print("Canal:", self.canal, "\nVersion:", self.version)
        #print(df)

        #add columns and format
        self.datos['Canal'] = "email"
        self.datos['CampaignID'] = 'md19'
        self.datos['FechaCarga'] = '29/07/2019'
        self.datos['Version'] = '1'
        self.datos['locale'] = "es"

        print(self.datos)

    def __iter__(self):
       return self.datos.itertuples()


data = [{'a': 'cod_persona2'}, {'a':'cod_persona'}]

# Creates DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mk = MkCloud(df)
mk.imprimir()

with open('huevos.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(mk)
```

De cualquier forma, lo correcto y más sencillo es usar `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` como ya se ha comentado.